# Map key code to specific forward search query

Tags: key-bindings, search

I'm trying to remap `<leader>t` to search for a specific string `[ ]` to save time running `/\[ \]` every time I search for it.

Things I've tried `:nnoremap <leader>t /\[ \]<CR>` but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I works for me using Vim 9.0. Your mapping is define for normal mode. Do you confirm that you are using it in normal mode and not in insert mode? Do you have other mapping that starts with `<leader>t`? What is the output of the Vim command `verbose map <leader>t`?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is meaningless. What do you do? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Etc.

Comment: I _suspect_ `:nnoremap <leader>t /\\[ \\]<CR>` might work